# View not updating on Set changes in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In Vue.js, I have this pieces of code (with Typescript Vue.js 2 and classed components):

```js
toggle(id: string): void {
    if (this.selectedIds.has(id)) {
      this.selectedIds.delete(id);
    } else {
      this.selectedIds.add(id);
    }
  }
```

and

```js
get handledUsers() {
    return this.users.map((user) => ({
      ...user,
      selected: this.selectedIds.has(user._id),
    }));
  }
```

where `selectedIds` is a `Set<string>`.

The problem is that in Vue.js, Set is not modified as Array, so it seems that when I update the Set, Vue.js does not detects it as if I did a `.splice()` of an array. How can I make the view update?

Comment: Have you tried with "this.forceUpdate()" ?

Comment: The question isn't precise. "get handledUsers" - do you use component classes? This isn't something that is known without saying. Do you use Vue 2? The question should mention this. Vue 3 supports reactive Set

Comment: Yes, it is with Vuejs and with component classes, it should be understandable but I can edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key to the element or component that you want to be updated, and then change the key value. Changing the key value of an element or a component would make theme rerender.

Here is an example:

```
<div :key="refreshKey" >
    some content...
</div>
```

Changing the value of refreshKey would cause this div to rerender and update it's content. So you should define a refreshKey in your components data, and then change it's value in your toggle method, for example from true to false.